# How I can use my classlibary in my ASP.NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, class-library, web-setup-project

I have a problem with my own classlibary "tarasov_lib.dll". I have a ASP.NET Application and I make a reference to my tarasov_lib.dll and if I test the webapp local it works fine but i make a websetup and install the application in my IIS on a other server I get a Error with the number 404: File or Folder not Found. Without my ddl it works :(

But I want use my classlibary :P

[image]

Comment: You can use your class library adding reference in VS. Without more details we can't answer it.

Comment: see refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481426/net-reference-copy-local-true-false-being-set-based-on-contents-of-gac

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not created the application within IIS.

- Start IIS Manager
- Create your website (if it does not exists)
- Right-Click your Directory (if it exists) and click "Convert to application"
- Alternatively click "Add application" to your website

Answer (score 1):

check you copy to local setting in your reference dll folder ..may be you missing to copy the dll in the setup package...