# MSBuild exclude satellite assemblies from output

Tags: c#, msbuild, satellite-assembly

Is it possible to tell MSBuild to NOT copy the satellite asssemblies for a certain assembly or for all?

I have a nuget package, which contains resource assemblies, but I do not want to include them in my output.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set [CopyLocal=false](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2481426/147211)

Comment: I still want the assembly to be copied, but not the satellite assemblies, which are included in the nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate folder for deployment like \Build_Archive where output is copied too - and add some lines to the build script to copy your assemblies, but not the satellite-assemblies to those folders - that way, the Build_Archive always has just the files needed for your deployment.

i.e. my current script copies to the build# labeled folder and to the Current folder - so Current always has the latest, and we maintain a history of prior builds - like:

```
C:\Build_Archive\AppName\Current
C:\Build_Archive\AppName\1.0.0.1
C:\Build_Archive\AppName\1.0.0.2
```

So something like this at the end of your build script (replace `<values>` for your stuff. Our script uses an external DLL to manage version numbers, etc. so not included here):

```
 <!-- . . . -->
 <DropLocation>\\<serverName>\Build_Archive\${BuildDefinition}</DropLocation>
 <!-- . . . -->

 <!-- Version numbers major and build are replaced by outside calls not shown -->
 <PropertyGroup>
   <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
   <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
   <VersionService>0</VersionService>
   <VersionBuild>0</VersionBuild>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="BuildNumberOverrideTarget">
 <!-- Create a custom build number, matching the assembly version -->
 <!-- . . . -->
 <!-- …  custom version code call – returns / sets VersionMajor and VersionBuild -->
  <PropertyGroup>
   <BuildNumber>$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(VersionMajor).$(VersionMinor).$(VersionService).$(VersionBuild)</BuildNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="Build number set to &quot;$(BuildNumber)&quot;" />
  <Message Text="$(SolutionRoot)"/>
 </Target>


 <Target Name="AfterCompile">
 <!-- Call Copy process after the build -->
  <CallTarget Targets="CleanUp"/>
  <CallTarget Targets="StageBuild"/>
  <CallTarget Targets="CopyFiles"/>
 </Target>

 <!-- Target : Clean Current Folder for next build -->
 <Target Name="CleanUp">
  <Message Text="**** Entering::CleanUp ****"/>
  <CreateItem Include="\\<server name>\Build_Archive\<appName>\Current\**\*.*">
   <Output ItemName="PreviousFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Delete Files="@(PreviousFiles)" ContinueOnError="true" />
 </Target>

 <!-- Target:StageBuild -->
 <Target Name="StageBuild">
 <ItemGroup>
  <BldCurrent Include="\\<server name>\Build_Archive\<appName>\Current\"/>
 </ItemGroup>
 <Message Text="@(BldCurrent)"/>
 <Message Text="$(SolutionRoot)"/>
 <!— Here – replace next line with commands to copy only the files you want to deploy -->
  <Exec Command="xcopy /y /r /e $(SolutionRoot)\..\bin\*.* @(BldCurrent)"/>
 </Target>

 <!-- Target : Copy files from Current to BuildNum folder -->
 <Target Name="CopyFiles">
  <Exec Command="xcopy /y /r /e $(DropLocation)\Current\Debug\*.* $(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Debug\"/>

  <Exec Command="Del /Q $(DropLocation)\Current\Debug\*.config"/>
  <Exec Command="Del /Q $(DropLocation)\Current\Debug\*.dll"/>
  <Exec Command="Del /Q $(DropLocation)\Current\Debug\*.exe"/>
  <Exec Command="Del /Q $(DropLocation)\Current\Debug\*.application"/>
  <Exec Command="Del /Q $(DropLocation)\Current\Debug\*.pdb"/>
  <Exec Command="Del /Q $(DropLocation)\Current\Debug\*.txt"/>
  <Exec Command="Del /Q $(DropLocation)\Current\Debug\*.xml"/>
 </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the MSBuild with this parameters:

```
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False
```

This will apply web.config transformation as VisualStudio would do.
In addition, the bin folder output is also the same as in a VisualStudio publish. Satellite Assemblies are not copied directly into the bin folder and remain in their bin subfolders.

See also:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alming/2015/01/19/using-web-config-transformations-and-release-manager/
- https://vosseburchttechblog.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2014/03/20/how-to-apply-web-config-transformations-during-tfs-build/
- [Publish website without roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282880/publish-website-without-roslyn)