# .net 4.6 framework downgrade to 4.5 framework rosyln error

Tags: c#, asp.net, release

My Local iis is working , but publish project and this bug appears

[image]

Comment: Modify your question and include the full error code output, what you have done to try and debug your error, etc. One thing you can do is modify `web.config` to display error messages [`<customErrors mode="Off" />`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx) **only while you try to isolate the issue**. One can _guess_ that you have [issues with Roslyn dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32282880/304683) when you downgraded to 4.5

Comment: Clearly the error page shows a link to "Detailed Compiler Output". Grab more data and add them to this question.